# npm E2E test is getting timed out when running in Docker but getting passed when running on local machine

Tags: javascript, selenium, docker, nightwatch.js, google-chrome-headless

Image/Box :   gfy94/wercker-chromium-node:v0.0.2 
Docker-Selenium Image Version : node-chrome
Docker Version: 17.12.1-ce,
OS:  Ubuntu 16.04

Hi, I'm trying to run npm E2E test in docker box (Ubuntu 16.04) with node version 6.9.3. It is running headlessly on local and all test cases are getting passed, but when I'm doing this on our local docker , it is taking much time to start and after passing few test cases it is getting stopped, due to timed out. I'm using headless chrome to run test on docker. Actually, in the end I have to run test on wercker. So, currently I'm just running it on local docker.

In nightwatch.js , these are the chrome properties :

```
  >   desiredCapabilities: {
  >     javascriptEnabled: true,
  >     acceptSslCerts: true,
  >     browserName: 'chrome',
  >     chromeOptions: {
  >     args: ['headless', 'no-sandbox', 'disable-gpu','window-size=1100,800'],
  >     },
  >    },
```

**## Expected Behavior -**

```
yashwant@yashwant-Inspiron-3537:~/website-node-react$ npm run test:e2e:desktop -- --tag authorised-bulk

  > website-node-react@1.0.0 test:e2e:desktop /home/yashwant/website-node-react
  > APP_DEVICE='desktop' nightwatch --config nightwatch.js "--tag" "authorised-bulk"

Starting selenium server... started - PID:  8410

[Authorised Bulk] Test Suite
================================

Running:  Authorised checkout, bulk products
 ✔ Element <//div[@class="modal-base  modal-base--after-open modal-base--  sticky-top"]//p[text()="Bangalore"]> was visible after 53 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <//div[@tabindex="-100"]//a[text()="Bangalore"]> was visible after 46 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <//a[contains(text(),"Login")]> was visible after 336 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <//div[@role="tabpanel"]//input[@name="email"]> was visible  after 64 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <//div[@role="tabpanel"]//input[@name="password"]> was visible after 47 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <//button[contains(text(),"Sign In")]> was visible after 67 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <(//a[starts-with(@href, "/bangalore/product")])[1]> was visible after 2781 milliseconds.
 Warn: WaitForElement found 4 elements for selector "//span[text()="Available in Bulk"]". Only the first one will be checked.
 ✔ Element <//span[text()="Available in Bulk"]> was visible after 2358 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <//a[contains(text(),"Quantity:")]> was visible after 1114 milliseconds.
✔ Passed [equal]: object == object
✔ Passed [equal]: 0 == 0
✔ Element <//button[@value = 2]> was visible after 247 milliseconds.
✔ Element <//button[text()="Buy Now"]> was visible after 370 milliseconds.
✔ Element <//div/p[contains(text(), "Order Summary")]> was visible after 1741 milliseconds.
✔ Element <//a[contains(text(),"Quantity:")]> was visible after 61 milliseconds.
✔ Passed [equal]: object == object
✔ Passed [equal]: 0 == 0
✔ Element <//button[@value = 2]> was visible after 37 milliseconds.
✔ Element <//button[text()="PROCEED TO NEXT STEP"]> was visible after 36 milliseconds.
  Warn: WaitForElement found 83 elements for selector "//button[contains(text(),"DELIVER HERE")]". Only the first one will be checked.
✔ Element <//button[contains(text(),"DELIVER HERE")]> was visible after 1216 milliseconds.
✔ Element <//li[text()="Cash/Card on Delivery"]> was visible after 1664 milliseconds.

OK. 21 assertions passed. (31.36s)
```

**## Actual Behavior -**

```
root@7ccf6a97ea58:/website-node-react# npm run test:e2e:desktop -- --tag authorised-bulk

 > website-node-react@1.0.0 test:e2e:desktop /website-node-react
 > APP_DEVICE='desktop' nightwatch --config nightwatch.js "--tag" "authorised-bulk"

Starting selenium server... started - PID:  945

[Authorised Bulk] Test Suite
================================

Running:  Authorised checkout, bulk products
 ✔ Element <//div[@class="modal-base  modal-base--after-open modal-base--sticky-top"]//p[text()="Bangalore"]> was visible after 44 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <//div[@tabindex="-100"]//a[text()="Bangalore"]> was visible after 47 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <//a[contains(text(),"Login")]> was visible after 323 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <//div[@role="tabpanel"]//input[@name="email"]> was visible after 41 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <//div[@role="tabpanel"]//input[@name="password"]> was visible after 39 milliseconds.
 ✔ Element <//button[contains(text(),"Sign In")]> was visible after 53 milliseconds.
 ✖ Timed out while waiting for element <(//a[starts-with(@href, "/bangalore/product")])[1]> to be present for 10000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
at Object.waitForProductVisibilty (/website-node-react/e2e/desktop/pages/home.js:19:12)
at Object.Authorised checkout, bulk products (/website-node-react/e2e/desktop/tests/authorised-bulk.js:27:14)


 FAILED:  1 assertions failed and 6 passed (30.476s)

 _________________________________________________

TEST FAILURE:  1 assertions failed, 6 passed. (32.172s)
```

Please, help me out in running these test cases seamlessly on docker also.

Comment: Your code trial and the relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it. What do you mean by code trial ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the trace logs on your local machine the *xpath* as `//a[starts-with(@href, "/bangalore/product")])[1]` is getting resolved successfully. Hence the following log is generated :

```
Element <(//a[starts-with(@href, "/bangalore/product")])[1]> was visible after 2781 milliseconds.
```

But the same *xpath* as `//a[starts-with(@href, "/bangalore/product")])[1]` is not getting resolved through *Docker*. As a immediate alternative you can try changing the quotes as follows :

```
<(//a[starts-with(@href, '/bangalore/product')])[1]>
```

Now, as the intended element is the **first** element returned through `findElements()` you can simply mention the `xpath` as:

```
"//a[starts-with(@href, '/bangalore/product')]"
```

As an alternative you can try an `xpath` with the keyword **contains** as follows :

```
"//a[contains(@href, '/bangalore/product')]"
```

Another alternative would be to try the `CSS` (starts-with) as follows :

```
"a[href^='/bangalore/product']"
```

The other alternative would be to try the `CSS` (contains) as follows :

```
"a[href*='/bangalore/product']"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think problem is not with Xpath as it is getting passed few times in docker as well. Here, main problem is test cases are running very slow in docker. Suppose during e2e test cases, xpath for sign in executed then docker might takes a lot of time to render the next page and thus the next xpath is getting timed out, sometimes. But this is not happening is local as it is running seamlessly and fast on local machine.

Comment: Incase it's a timing issue induce a waiter through [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) in-conjunction with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

Comment: I have increased the timeout to 1 min ( 60 sec ), still no luck.